# Omit null fields from elasticsearch results

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Is there anyway to prevent elasticsearch from returning null fields from queries? Right now it's returning the following.

```
{
  "someField": 123,
  "somethingElse": null
}
```

But I need it to omit any null fields

```
{
  "someField": 123
}
```

I've looked around and everything I find is about omitting entire documents from the results if a certain field is null. But I want all the documents returned just if any field is null that field should be omitted.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Curious if it is...

Comment: If you don't need/want null fields to be returned, the best choice you have is to not send them to ES in the first place.

Comment: @Val I'm not sending them when they are empty. I believe it happened because I added new fields which can be omitted when I send it to ES. I think this made ES update my mappings and now it returns null whenever those fields don't exist.